# Why is the method accepts only one argument?

Tags: scala

Looking at this nice Fibonacci implementation :

```
scala> val fibs = {
          def go(f0: Int, f1: Int): Stream[Int] =
          Stream.cons(f0, go(f1, f0+f1))
           go(0, 1)
          }
fibs: Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)
```

at first look it seems that it accepts two arguments go(f0: Int, f1: Int) but trying that will result TooManyArgumentsException 
however with one argument it works fine (as it should)

```
scala> fibs(9)
res23: Int = 34
```

how can one know the number of arguments fibs should accept ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fibs` is not a method, it's a value of type `Stream[Int]`.

When you write `fibs(9)`, you're calling `fibs.apply(9)`, which, for a `Stream`, selects an element by its index in the sequence (see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream)).

This is the same as :

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3,4)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> l(2)
res0: Int = 3
```